# Updating external list from sharepoint workflow - error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-list

I've created *page workflow* to update data in external list:

[image: Sharepoint workflow designer]

When I execute this workflow, I get an error. I don't know what causes the error:

[image: Sharepoint workflow error]

I've read about permissions to the Sharepoint system account. I feel like I've tried everything.
Do you have any ideas what can cause this error ? Is there any way of debugging such workflows in *Sharepoint designer* ? I've tried reading Sharepoint logs, but nothing interesting there.

TIA for any clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do that, I needed to configure *Secure Store Service* application:

[link 1](http://petersullivan.com.au/2010/12/15/the-workflow-could-not-update-the-item-in-the-external-data-source-make-sure-the-user-has-permissions-to-access-the-external-data-source-and-update-items/)

[link 2](http://petersullivan.com.au/2010/12/15/creating-list-items-in-an-external-list-with-sharepoint-designer-workflows/)